# Pass variables to Template Layout in CakePHP 3.x

Tags: cakephp-3.0

How can I pass variables to Template/Layout/default.ctp file (like "globally")?

I tried this:

```
src/Controller/PermissionsController.php:

public function myPermissions()
{
    return $this->request->getSession()->read('Auth.User.id');
}

src/Template/Layout/default.ctp:
use App\Controller\PermissionsController;
debug(PermissionsController::myPermissions());die;
```

and I'm getting this error: `Using $this when not in object context`

Answer (score 0):

I created a Config variable and use in template file:

```
src/Controller/AppController.php:
use Cake\Core\Configure;

[...]

public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    Configure::write('myPermissions', $this->myPermissions());
}

src/Template/Layout/default.ctp:
\Cake\Core\Configure::read('myPermissions');
```

Comment: You could also use `$this->set('myPermissions', $this->myPermissions());` in your initialize function and then directly reference `$myPermissions` in your layout.